# how can i find best value of t in this equation?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I need to evaluate
$$\tan^{-1} (x) - x = O(x^t)$$
as $x$ approaches $0$, in order to find the best value of $t$.

Big O notation is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

I tried: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan^{-1}(x) - x}{x^t}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with the power series expansion for $\arctan x$, namely
$$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+ \cdots,$$
(valid for $|x|\lt 1$, and even at $x=1$), then $t=3$ is immediate.

If the power series expansion is not familiar, one could do a search for a suitable $t$ by looking, as you are, at 
$$\frac{\arctan x-x}{x^t},\tag{1}$$ for various small integer values of $t$, starting at $t=1$.

Use **L'Hospital's Rule** to find the limit as $x\to 0$ of (1) first when $t=1$, then when $t=2$, then when $t=3$. At $t=3$ we get a non-zero limit.